# how many htaccess files there shall be?

Tags: .htaccess

How i shall organise htaccess files?
Shall there be a single file, or file in each folder?
I have somedomain/public/.htaccess, which puts url string to `$_REQUEST['url']` variable. This is the second part of the code below, and it works.

Later, i created somedomain/.htaccess with code for redirecting to https://www.
Two separate files did not work, thus i pasted the somedomain/public/.htaccess to somedomain/.htaccess. But nothing works. How to achieve these two functionalities. I means redirection to https://www and url fetching to variable. Where is the mistake below?

Shall i create somedomain/.htaccess,  somedomain/public/.htaccess,  somedomain/somefolder/.htaccess, ....

Or i shall have only one somedomain/.htaccess which deals with all redirections?
If i have only one somedomain/.htaccess as it is below, how i shall redirect 
`somedomain` to `somedomain/public/index.php`
`somedomain/{url not matching somedomain/public/index.php/parameters}` to `error`

folder structure

```
somedomain.com/
      .htaccess
      /public
            #.htaccess #the second part of code, which i copied to somedomain.com/.htaccess
            index.php
```

.htaccess in somedomain.com/

```
#first part of htaccess
# Rewrite to HTTPS:
# If www. is already there it will be included, if not
# it will be catched by the subsequent rule.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 
#[L,R=301]

# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
# [NC] is a case-insensitive match
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 
#[L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
# the default webpage loaded by the server:
DirectoryIndex /public/index.php/security/login
IndexIgnore * 

#Second part of htaccess
#rules to fetch controller name and method name starting from /public/index.php/
RewriteBase /public/
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^index.php?(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I am gettting the error : The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. ...
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Previously i had only the second part of .htaccess in somedomain.com/public .

Server error logs:

```
[Thu Apr 20 08:37:36 2017] [error] [client 213.133.81.6] File does not exist: /home/gintare/public_html/typejoy.biz/500.shtml
[Thu Apr 20 08:45:43 2017] [alert] [client 213.133.81.6] /home/gintare/public_html/typejoy.biz/.htaccess: Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbf', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Thu Apr 20 08:45:43 2017] [alert] [client 213.133.81.6] /home/gintare/public_html/typejoy.biz/.htaccess: Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbf', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Thu Apr 20 08:46:04 2017] [alert] [client 213.133.81.6] /home/gintare/public_html/typejoy.biz/.htaccess: Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbf', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Thu Apr 20 08:46:04 2017] [alert] [client 213.133.81.6] /home/gintare/public_html/typejoy.biz/.htaccess: Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbf', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Thu Apr 20 08:46:08 2017] [alert] [client 213.133.81.6] /home/gintare/public_html/typejoy.biz/.htaccess: Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbf', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Thu Apr 20 08:46:08 2017] [alert] [client 213.133.81.6] /home/gintare/public_html/typejoy.biz/.htaccess: Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbf', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Thu Apr 20 10:05:04 2017] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `typejoy.biz' does NOT match server name!?
[Thu Apr 20 10:50:27 2017] [error] [client 115.118.128.202] File does not exist: /home/gintare/public_html/typejoy.biz/favicon.ico
[Thu Apr 20 10:50:27 2017] [error] [client 115.118.128.202] File does not exist: /home/gintare/public_html/typejoy.biz/404.shtml
[Thu Apr 20 10:51:41 2017] [error] [client 115.118.128.202] File does not exist: /home/gintare/public_html/typejoy.biz/favicon.ico
[Thu Apr 20 10:51:41 2017] [error] [client 115.118.128.202] File does not exist: /home/gintare/public_html/typejoy.biz/404.shtml
```

Comment: So what does your http servers error log file say?

Comment: what mean this rule `^index.php?(.+)$`?

Comment: `^index.php?(.+)$` means index.php/controller/method/parameter1/parameter2  `$` means that everything in brackets shall be assign to variable url. In brackets will be everything that goes after index.php/ It will be /controller/method/parameters . You can retrieve `url` in your index.php file as `$_REQUEST['url'] ` and anlise, then call controller and method and pass parameters

Comment: `require_once INC_ROOT.'/src/LogBundle/Controller/'.ucfirst($this->url[0]).'Controller.php';`  `$this->contr = new $cnt();`

Comment: `if( method_exists($this->contr, $this->url[1].'Action') ){`
                   `$this->method = $this->url[1].'Action';` `}`

Comment: `$this->prms = !empty($this->url) ? array_values($this->url) : [];`

Comment: `call_user_func( [$this->contr, $this->method],  $this->prms );`

Comment: I have appended error logs

Comment: the `\xef\xbb\xbf` means BOM, so the config-file should be saved w/o this mark, ie utf-8 w/o bom

Comment: get sure the `%{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME}` is not empty, consider the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` instead

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#how

Comment: [You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)